# How to recursively replace all negative value with 0 in python?

Tags: python, arrays

i need to recursively replace all the negative values with zero in this user inputted array. my output should be

```
Enter an array of numbers e.g. [2,1,3,1,2]:

[2, 4, 3, -2, 1, -2, -3, 9]

Original Array:

[2, 4, 3, -2, 1, -2, -3, 9]

After replacing negative numbers with Zero:

[2, 4, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 9]
```

however I get this as my output:

```
Enter an array of numbers e.g. [2,-1,3,-1,2]:
[2, 4, 3, -2, 1, -2, -3, 9]
Original Array:
[2, 4, 3, -2, 1, -2, -3, 9]Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/tessa/Downloads/test3f.py", line 23, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:/Users/tessa/Downloads/test3f.py", line 19, in <module>
    substitute_negatives(array, 0)
  File "c:/Users/tessa/Downloads/test3f.py", line 13, in <module>
    replace(array, currentIndex + 1)
builtins.NameError: name 'replace' is not defined
```

if you could help me fix the error in my code (I'm new to python and am struggling to identify my mistake)

```
def substitute_negatives(array, currentIndex) :
    if currentIndex < len(array) :
        if array[currentIndex] < 0 :
            array[currentIndex] = 0
        replace(array, currentIndex + 1)
    return  
  
def main():
    array = eval(input("Enter an array of numbers e.g. [2,-1,3,-1,2]:\n"))
    print("Original Array:\n" + str(array))
    substitute_negatives(array, 0)
    print("After replacing negative numbers with Zero:\n" + str(array)) 
    
    
main()
```

Comment: You never defined the `replace` function anywhere.

Comment: Looks like a typo: `replace` should be `substitute_negatives` ?

Comment: @Nk03, it looks like JoannaGreen is interested in a recursive solution.

Comment: Don't use `eval` to parse a list display; you are just allowing the user to enter something that *isn't* an array. Take a comma-separated list as input, and split it yourself: `array = [int(x) for input().split(",")]`.

Comment: Also, don't use recursion for simple iteration. `[0 if x < 0 else x for x in array]`. If you really need to do it in place, just use a `for` loop: `for i, x in enumerate(array): if x < 0: array[i] = 0`.

Comment: Shouldn't it be ```substitute_negatives(array, currentIndex + 1)``` instead of ```replace```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the term *recursive*

Answer (score 0):

i have figured out my error. the correct code is:

```
def substitute_negatives(array, currentIndex) :
    if currentIndex < len(array) :
        if array[currentIndex] < 0 :
            array[currentIndex] = 0
        substitute_negatives(array, currentIndex + 1)
    return  
  
def main():
    array = eval(input("Enter an array of numbers e.g. [2,-1,3,-1,2]:\n"))
    print("Original Array:\n" + str(array))
    substitute_negatives(array, 0)
    print("After replacing negative numbers with Zero:\n" + str(array)) 
    
    
main()
```